# Duplicated Label in add_menu_page

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, customization, admin

I have created a function for a theme customization.

```
function create_theme_option() {

        add_menu_page(  'Manage Options', //Page Title 

                        'Theme Option', //WP Administrator Menu Title

                        'manage_options', //

                        'theme-options', //Link to a page to your Administration Area

                        'deploy_theme_options', //Function Name

                        get_template_directory_uri() . '/Plugins/Background Changer/images/icons/icon.png',//Menu Icon 

                        99);

        add_submenu_page("theme-options", "Theme Settings", "Theme Settings", 1, "theme-settings", "theme_settings");

        add_submenu_page("theme-options", "Manage Header", "Manage Header", 1, "manage-header", "manage_header");

        add_submenu_page("theme-options", "Social Media", "Social Media Links", 1, "social-media", "social_media");

        add_submenu_page("theme-options", "Catalog Manager", "Catalog Manager", 1, "catalog-manager", "catalog_manager");

    }
```

but I noticed that after the label "Theme Option" there is another text appear next to it as "Theme Option". Check the Image below:

[image: http://leojarina.info/stock-data/images/screenshot.jpg]

How can I fix this? Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Basharat was pretty close. Here is a cleaner way I use in my plugins:

```
add_menu_page(
    '',                     // No need to have this
    'My Plugin',            // Menu Label
    'manage_options',
    'my_plugin_settings',   // (*) Shared slug
    'your_function',
    plugins_url('myplugin/images/icon.png'),
    81
);

add_submenu_page(
    'my_plugin_settings',   // (*) Shared slug
    'My Plugin Settings',   // Subpage Title
    'Settings',             // Submenu Label
    'manage_options',
    'my_plugin_settings',   // (*) Shared slug
    'your_function'
);
```

**Source:** Coffee, trial and error ;)

Comment: The key is the 'my_plugin_settings' slug in BOTH the menu and submenu.  And TWICE in the submenu.

Answer (score 2):

For fix this issue you can use the remove_submenu_page, 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page.

example:

remove_submenu_page ('my-menu-slug','my-menu-slug')

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution, but it means there'll be no callback function associated with the top-level menu item defined in `add_menu_page` ('Theme option' in the OP's example) and that clicking on it will direct the user to the first submenu page instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below to remove the duplicate entry of Menu in Sub-Menu.

```
<?php 
/* Add top level menu */
add_menu_page(
    'MyTheme', 
    'MyTheme Menu Label',
    'edit_themes', 
    'theme_admin',        // menu slug
    'functions.php',        // function
    get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/img/favicon.png',
    31
);

/* remove duplicate menu hack */
add_submenu_page(
    'theme_admin',        // parent slug, same as above menu slug
    '',        // empty page title
    '',        // empty menu title
    'edit_themes',        // same capability as above
    'theme_admin',        // same menu slug as parent slug
    'functions.php',        // same function as above
}
?>
```

This isn't too clean, but afaik the only way to hide the duplicate submenu.

**Reference:**
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52675/how-to-remove-duplicate-link-from-add-menu-page

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the capability parameter which should not be 99

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: Nothings change, still got the same problem

Comment: I think you should try changing "theme-options" which have to be unique and should not be here

Comment: I tried but there's nothing happen, I also change the 99 to different values but I got the same problem.  Please help!

Comment: Did you change too the first parameter of all your add_submenu_page ?

Comment: And if you remove your add_menu_page function ?

Answer (score 0):

The only working way i found is to set the `add_menu_page` $capabilties to unknown, so something like `'unknown'`, this will hide the page or the submenu, but the menus will still be shown on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate menu just explicitly define how you want it to appear (if with another name) or remove it. Let's see both cases below.

Case 1 - You want your first plugin page to appear but with another name:

```
<?php
    
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_plugin');

function register_my_plugin()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Welcome my plugin', // page title (whatever)
        'My Plugin Name', // menu title (whatever)
        'manage_options', // necessary capacity
        'page-1', // page slug
        'fn_page_1', // your function to load page 1 resources
        'dashicons-lightbulb' //a cute icon from developer.wordpress.org/resource/
    );
    
    add_submenu_page( //Identical to the menu except for the label
        'page-1',  // parent slug
        'Welcome', // page title (whatever)
        'Welcome',  // Label do submenu (whatever) --> (replaces duplicate My Plugin Name)
        'manage_options', // necessary capacity
        'page-1',   // your function to load page 1 resources
        'fn_page_1', // function to load page 1 resources again
    );
    
    add_submenu_page(
        'page-1',  // parent slug
        'Next Page', // page title (whatever)
        'Next Page',  // Submenu label  (whatever) 
        'manage_options', // necessary capacity
        'page-2',   // page slug
        'fn_page_2', // your function to load page 2 resources
    );
} //close register_my_plugin
```

Case 2 - You want remove first plugin page from **submenu**:

With all code included, just add this before close the function `register_my_plugin()`

```
    remove_submenu_page(
        'page-1','page-1'
    );
} //close register_my_plugin
```

[image]